# Spring Throwing CannotCreateTransactionException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The scenario is that I want to handle the exception should the DB go down.

My assumption was that the DataAccessException would be thrown. However instead when I bring the DB down the exception that I get from the repository method is CannotCreateTransactionException. Is this right.

My application is a Spring CommandLine application and below is the code of How I access it

```
CustomerRepository cr = appContext.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);
    cr.exists(customerId);
```

It works as expected but when the DB is down why is it throwing CannotCreateTransactionException. Or is my understanding of DataAccessException wrong.

When does DataAccessException come and when does CannotCreateTransactionException come?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source code, you will see that `DataAccessException` and its sub classes, are used to handle all kinds of error when you access you data in table, but not DB. Like the record is locked by other transaction, there will be some kind of `DataAccessException`.

If you stop your DB during accessing database, the error maybe related with the database driver and datasource lib based on that. For example, whether you have a connection pool.

So, I think you can not specify which Exception will be thrown when the DB down.

Comment: So, in general, How would I handle DB Exceptions? Let's say for example I am making use of spring-retry and I need to set the retry policies based on the exceptions that are being thrown.?

Comment: If your DB access or update failed. Most of the time, it is because of your business code, retry will not make any difference. In the normal, for the resource like DB, we assume it will be available all the time. If your DB is too busy to handle new sql, you should check is there any SQL problem you write. If not, then you need to upgrade your DB to a better server or distributed. If the SQL failed because of data lock, check your transaction code. In a word, retry on DB access will only make it worse.